# Disable keys on a specific keyboard (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

What is the easiest way to disable a key on a *specific* keyboard, while still leaving it functioning on other keyboards?

I have a gaming keypad which for some reason sends function keys when I use the buttons for switching profiles. I would like Windows to ignore all function key presses coming from it.

I have tried several utilities, including the Windows Keyboard Filter, but they all seem to disable keys globally, not per-keyboard.

Comment: It's not possible unless the keyboard has it's own programmable functionality.

Comment: It's possible in Linux by assigning a custom keyboard layout to a particular device. Are you sure it can't be done in Windows?

Comment: I have the same question. Bought myself the Redragon K585, and the profile switching keys ALSO send F9-F12. I've tested with AHK whether the driver or management software uses the FKey signals to switch profiles, but it does not - you can just disable F9-F12 and it'll still switch profiles.